# Can I change stroke color for specific line segments in the Canvas path?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Can I change stroke color for specific line segments in the Canvas path?

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="c">
        <Path x:Name="path" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure x:Name="figure" StartPoint="10,100">
                        <LineSegment x:Name="s0" Point="10,100"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment x:Name="s1" Point="100,100" />
                        <LineSegment x:Name="s2" Point="100,50" />
                        <LineSegment x:Name="s3" Point="150,10" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

For example, if I want to change Stroke color of the line path between StartPoint and LineSegment s1, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to start a new path every time you change color. Stop the path after S1, switch color, then start a new pathFigure with this new color defined.

Comment: There is a property in the LineSegment - IsStroked. When it's set to false specific LineSegment color is changed to transparent, as I suppose. Maybe I can change the default color for the LineSegmnet when IsStroked property set to false and be able to manipulate the colors for each segment I want to mark with different color?

Comment: @Max Naumov That sounds like a good idea. Go ahead and try that and tell me the results

Comment: Setting IsStroked to false does not draw a transparently stroked segment. Instead, it does not draw the segment at all, which is something different. You can't set the stroke of a segment that isn't drawn. As said in the answer, you'll have to create a new Path element

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one path for each color... As you said in your suggestion, to change the color between s0 and s1 must be:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="c">
        <Path x:Name="path1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure x:Name="figure" StartPoint="10,100">
                        <LineSegment x:Name="s0" Point="10,100"></LineSegment>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path x:Name="path2" Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure x:Name="figure2" StartPoint="10,100">
                        <LineSegment x:Name="s1" Point="100,100" />
                        <LineSegment x:Name="s2" Point="100,50" />
                        <LineSegment x:Name="s3" Point="150,10" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas> </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the untested method of using a Pen/Brush.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32891846)